# Uninstall parallels plesk panel, I can't

Tags: windows, uninstallation, plesk, parallels

I installed parallels plesk panel 9.5 for windows, on windows server 2003 x64, now I can not uninstall, I get this error:

The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if you are running Windows in safe mode, or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed.

Windows is not running in safe mode, and i try to install windows installer, but i cant.

And not that way I can do to uninstall. can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I just finished uninstalling Plesk Panel 11 using the Windows "Uninstall a program" feature.  It seemed to work as it displayed a DOS window and informed me of each module it was uinstalling but it did not remove anything from IIS. Also the entire Parallels directory structure was still fully intact after the uninstall "successfully" completed.

I had to manually remove websites and application pools from IIS and manually delete the entire directory and file structure in windows explorer.  However, in order to do this I had to first stop all the MailEnable Services as well as end the Process for METray.exe.

In other words, removing Plesk Panel completely was a mostly manual process.

Answer (score 1):

Parallels plesk 9.5 and 10.1-10.3 does not support uninstall as for unix/linux as for windows OSes.

If i'm not mistaken plesk supports uninstall for windows starting from 10.4 or it's 11 version. Need to reread release notes.

As options for uninstall might be following:

1. Try to upgrate to plesk 11 and them uninstall plesk (accually I do not so sure in this option and will be good to check it before trying on real server);
2. redeploy server if it doesn't important for you;
3. stop panel at the services and do not care about it. Also you can remove panel from filesystem and from iis manually.